# New item added to session on every request

Tags: asp.net, session

I found this behaviour by accident, as I return the count of items in a session in an error message and found that some sessions had as many as 120 items in them (they should have 1!).  On further investigation I found that every request seems to add an item into the session.  They are all negative integers, like -710, -140 -528.  I can't seem to see a pattern in what number comes up.

I have checked my code for any interactions with the Session object and as far as I can tell it is not me.  I store one item in the session which is my own object which has a number of other properties on it.  My session state is SQL server, and I am only serialising a certain set of values that need to be kept.

Has anyone seen anything like this or has any advice on where I can troubleshoot further?

Thank you in advance.

-- Edit, as requested - first where I count the items in the session - this is done in the page load event of my master page.  I loop through so I could inspect using the debugger.

```
int itemCount = Session.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
{
    object o = Session[i];
}
```

-- here is where I add my custom object to the session.  This is called at session start and in my master page.  It runs on a "get, but if not there, create" principle.

```
HttpSessionState Session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
HttpRequest Request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

if (Session == null)
    return null;

SessionData sessionData = (SessionData)Session[StaticNames.SESSION_NAME];
if (sessionData == null)
{
    sessionData = new SessionData();
    Session.Add(StaticNames.SESSION_NAME, sessionData);
}
```

I also have this to get the SessionData object from the session:

```
public SessionData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
{
    this.IsManualLogin = (bool)info.GetValue("IsManualLogin", typeof(bool));
    this.HasAskedUserForLocation = (bool)info.GetValue("HasAskedUserForLocation", typeof(bool));
    // ... etc, more items for all users here

    int? loginID = null;
    try
    {
        loginID = info.GetInt32("LoginID");
    }
    catch
    {
        return;
    }

    this.LoginID = loginID.Value;
    // ... etc, more items for logged in users only
}
```

There is also an equivalent method for adding this data to the SerializationInfo used for SqlSessionState.

Comment: Can you show the code where you display the number of items in the Session? And the code that adds an item to the Session (the context around this one is important, so make sure to indicate where that code is called from)?

Comment: Thank you Jadarnel, I've posted up lots of code, any further questions, please feel free to ask.  In fact I'm going to edit it down a bit, you don't really need to see EVERY item I stick in there...

Comment: So the values of these rogue Session entries are negative integers? What are the keys for these entries? That might be a clue as to what's wrong.  Thank you for your quick response in adding the code, by the way.

Comment: How can you tell what the key is?  I've traversed through the debugger for some time trying to pull out a key but I can never find one...

Comment: In your first code snippet (the one that loops through the Session items), add `string keyName = Session.Keys[i];`. That should let you see the keys.

Comment: Oh yeah, duh.  Too many late nights.  That has cleared up the cause.  I am using the ajax control toolkit NoBot control to make sure a user doesn't post to a page too quickly and the other bits that it does.  Apparently it is the thing adding all this nonsense into my session.  They should really have that on the label: "will use all your memory on storing numbers in your session".  Sigh.

Thanks for the help.  Would you like to pose an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Haha, glad I could help =)  Don't worry about giving me credit - you figured it out.  All I did was point you in the right direction.  You should post an answer, so maybe it will help future victims of this odd NoBot behavior!

Answer (score 1):

Credit to the modest jadarnel27.

It turns out the Ajax Control Toolkit NoBot control adds an integer into your session on every request.  My website has an auto 40 second refresh, similar to facebook, so this probably would have brought the whole thing crashing down at some point and I am lucky to find it now.  Should anyone else consider using the NoBot control, be warned about this behaviour!